# How far can an x-ray travel through water?

Tags: electrons, water, x-rays, radio-frequency, attenuation

I am studying x-ray's and how they interact with different mediums, but I am a bit confused on the distances an x-ray can travel through different mediums such as water.

Let's take an x-ray with 3 nanometres wavelength, from what I've read this can penetrate several centimeters in water. From what I know about radiofrequencies, if I increase the intensity of the signal, it will travel further. Can this also be applied to x-rays?

What I don't understand is that a 3nm x-ray has a power output of about 100 eV, how can I increase the intensity without affecting the wavelength?

Also, will increasing the intensity allow it to penetrate further into water?

Thanks for the help!

Antoine

Comment: Sorry I meant 100 eV

Comment: Re, " a 3nm x-ray has a power output of about 100 eV." That's not power. That's the energy delivered by each photon. Power is the product of the energy per photon multiplied by the number of photons per unit time.

Comment: Re, "how can I increase the intensity without affecting the wavelength?" Intensity of the X-rays from an electron tube will be proportional to beam current. Wavelength will depend on the tube voltage. I don't know how you can increase the current without changing the voltage, but I'm guessing that you'd have to change the geometry of the tube.

Answer (score 2):

The intensity has nothing to do with the range in matter.  That depends on the energy of the x-rays. From [here](https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Radiography/Physics/attenuationCoef.htm) The linear attenuation coefficient (µ) describes the fraction of a beam of x-rays or gamma rays that is absorbed or scattered per unit thickness of the absorber. This value basically accounts for the number of atoms in a cubic cm volume of material and the probability of a photon being scattered or absorbed from the nucleus or an electron of one of these atoms.

There is also a Mass Attenuation Coefficient. From the same source, Since a linear attenuation coefficient is dependent on the density of a material, the mass attenuation coefficient is often reported for convenience.  Consider water for example.  The linear attenuation for water vapor is much lower than it is for ice because the molecules are more spread out in vapor so the chance of a photon encounter with a water particle is less.  Normalizing m by dividing it by the density of the element or compound will produce a value that is constant for a particular element or compound.  This constant (m/r) is known as the mass attenuation coefficient and has units of cm2/gm.

From [here](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ComTab/water.html) we get the following plot and table values are listed [here](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ComTab/water.html).

[image]

The intensity of X-rays will depend on the Voltage used in the X-ray tube.

The faction that gets thru is $$ \frac{I}{I_0}= e^{-\mu x}$$ where ${\mu }$ = linear attenuation coefficient and x is the distance the photon travels thru the medium.

Comment: Re, "...intensity has nothing to do with the range..." That depends on what you mean by "range." If the question really means, what depth of water is sufficient to attenuate the beam to below some arbitrary, "acceptable" flux, then the answer _does_ depend on the intensity of the source.

Comment: I'm familiar with the mass attenuation coefficient, but where I am confused is that can the same xray at 3nm penetrate further through water with a higher intensity? Similar as to a radio wave will travel further with a higher intensity?

Comment: No it won't. As you can see on the plot the attenuation coefficient is only dependent on the energy.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, I'm confused by what you are saying. The attenuation coefficient does not depend on intensity.

Comment: Yes, but the _intensity_ depends on intensity. Asking, "how far can an x-ray travel through ...?" sounds like, "how much ... do I need to shield myself against x-rays?" _IF_ that's the case, then the answer depends on the intensity of the source. Knowing the mass attenuation coefficient of the shield material, you can calculate what _fraction_ of the beam gets through a certain thickness, but your goal in building a shield is not to reduce the beam by so-many percent: Your goal is to reduce it to less than some "acceptable," absolute level. For a stronger source, you need a thicker shield.

Comment: yes, I agree, the higher the intensity the higher the number that gets thru. But it won't affect the percentage that gets thru.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I've updated my answer to show the equation for percentage getting thru.

Answer (score 0):

> Will increasing the intensity allow it to penetrate further into water?

Water, or any other material, does not *block* X-rays. It *attenuates* X-rays. For any given thickness of a given material some *fraction* of the incident beam will make it all the way through. You can calculate that fraction knowing the thickness of the material, the photon energy (e.g., your 100eV), and the the information from [@jmh's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/533632/74763).

The fraction will be a decaying exponential function of the thickness.  So, for example, if a certain thickness lets half of the beam through, then twice that thickness will let 1/4 of the beam through, three times the thickness will let 1/8th of the beam through, and so on.

From a pure mathematical perspective, no amount of shielding material will block 100% of the beam. But because of the exponential nature of the depth function, you can practically always build a thick enough shield to reduce the intensity below the noise threshold of your detector.

Comment: Yes exactly.  Good info. I should have started with that.  Thanks.